# High leverage Points In Logistic Regression in R

Tags: logistic

Do You Know Any Good R Package For This Model?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `rms` package will do this.  When a variable appears in multiple terms (e.g. $x, x^{2}$), the `which.influence` function tells you which observations are influential on any of the coefficients related to that predictor.

Comment: Thanks. But How To Calculate vj, bj, hj With R. I Need R Code

Comment: You can look at the source code for the `which.influence` function if you want to see how this is done.